# Hide submenu behind header

Tags: css, menu, z-index, translate-animation

I'm trying to make a simple top menu with one level of submenus. I want to animate them with `translate3d`, but I can't manage to get them to sit behind the header with `z-index`. I'm using Foundation, so the header looks a bit like this:

```css
#main-menu > li {
    position: relative;
}

#main-menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: transform 400ms ease; (omitted other prefixes)
    transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
}

#main-menu > li:hover ul {
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-3 small-12 columns">
            <a id="logo" href="/"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="large-9 small-12 columns">
            <nav>
                <ul id="main-menu" class="menu">
                    <li class="has-children">
                        <a href="/foo">Foo</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/foo/first">First Child</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/foo/second">Second Child</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So in the normal state the submenus `#main-menu ul` are translated vertically by their height so that when the main menus buttons are hovered the submenus slide down. However, I can't seem to make it so that the submenus are behind the entire header but appear above the content below.

Answer (score 0):

this may help to your.This can do in several ways.this is one of it.you can do it easily if you start to use bootstrap.this solution only use html, css and js.this may a quick help to you.

```
<!DOCTYPE> 
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li.one").mouseenter(function(){
        $("div.submenu").fadeIn(500,function(){
            $(this).mouseleave(function(){
                $(this).fadeOut(500);
            });
        });
    });
});

</script>
<style type="text/css">
body{
    margin: 0;
}
    ul{
        background-color:black;
    }
    ul li{
        color: white;
        list-style-type: none;
        display:inline;
        font-size:30px;
        width:100px;
        margin-left: 30px;
        margin-right: 30px;
    }
    div.submenu li{
        list-style-type: none;
        color: white;
        font-size: 30px;
        width:200px;
        background-color: black;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        top:-15px;
        left:550px;


    }
    div.submenu{
        display: none;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div style="text-align:center;">
  <ul>
    <li class="one">Basin &amp; Sinks</li>
    <li>Bathroom Accessories</li>
    <li>Showers </li>
    <li>Toilets</li>

  </ul>
  <div class="submenu">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
  </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your either your header or main menu (depending on the style you going for) to absolute with no z-index applied and then add a negative z-index to the absolute positioned sub-menu. this will hide the submenu content behind the parent elements.

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0:
    }
#header {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3;

  height:60px;
  position:relative;
  }

#main-menu {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:30px;
  list-style:none;
  }

#main-menu li > a {
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:1em 2em;
  }

#main-menu li.has-children ul {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:100%;
  -webkit-transition: transform 400ms ease;
    transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
  background:#f4f4f4;
  border:1px solid #e3e3e3;
  padding:1em;
  }

#main-menu li:hover ul {

    transform: translate3d(0,20%,0);
  }
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-3 small-12 columns">
            <a id="logo" href="/"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="large-9 small-12 columns">
            <nav>
                <ul id="main-menu" class="menu">
                    <li class="has-children">
                        <a href="/foo">Foo</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/foo/first">First Child</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/foo/second">Second Child</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```